# Check cell row in Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, rows, cells

I have a function to define a cell parameters in the table (I apply this function to unique strings only and it works well). 
But how can I determine cell row in the big dataset, but in specific dataframe?

Here's my function to check a row in the whole df:

```
def check_row(cond_name):
    from xlrd import open_workbook
    book = open_workbook("output.xlsx")
    for sheet in book.sheets():
        for rowidx in range(sheet.nrows):
            row = sheet.row(rowidx)
            for colidx, cell in enumerate(row):
                if cell.value == cond_name :
                    print("condition name is: ",cond_name)
                    return rowidx+1
```

But I also have subdataframes, such as         `f_list = df['Relevant findings'].values.tolist()[0:8]`, and I need to determine exact coordinates (row and column) of random string that is in the list. 
Is it possible?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to get a cell row (first appearance of specific string) in dataframe subset.

Comment: Try simply return(rowidx+1,colidx+1) --> This should return the coordinates of the column and the row